# how to place sliced images into a javascript table

Tags: javascript, html

```
 <html>
 
  <body>

  <div id="images">

 <table>
   <script type= "text/javascript">
      var myArray = new Array();

     myArray[0]= new Array("images/bcpot002_r1_c1.jpg");
     myArray[1] = new Array("images/bcpot002_r1_c2.jpg");
     myArray[2] = new Array("images/bcpot002_r1_c3.jpg");
     myArray[3] = new Array("images/bcpot002_r1_c4.jpg");
     myArray[4] = new Array("images/bcpot002_r1_c5.jpg");
 
 
 var  myArray2 = new Array();

    myArray2[0] = new Array("images/bcpot002_r2_c1.jpg");
    myArray2[1] = new Array("images/bcpot002_r2_c2.jpg");
    myArray2[2]= new  Array("images/bcpot002_r2_c3.jpg");
    myArray2[3] = new Array("images/bcpot002_r2_c4.jpg");
    myArray2[4] = new Array("images/bcpot002_r2_c5.jpg");

   
 var myArray3 = new  Array();

    myArray3[0] = new Array("images/bcpot002_r3_c1.jpg");
    myArray3[1] = new Array("images/bcpot002_r3_c2.jpg");
    myArray3[2] = new Array("images/bcpot002_r3_c3.jpg");
    myArray3[3] = new Array("images/bcpot002_r3_c4.jpg");
    myArray3[4] = new Array("images/bcpot002_r3_c5.jpg");
    

 var myArray4 = new  Array();

    myArray4[0] = new Array("images/bcpot002_r4_c1.jpg");
    myArray4[1] = new Array("images/bcpot002_r4_c2.jpg");
    myArray4[2] = new Array("images/bcpot002_r4_c3.jpg");
    myArray4[3] = new Array("images/bcpot002_r4_c3.jpg");
    myArray4[4] = new Array("images/bcpot002_r4_c3.jpg");
  

  for (var i=0; i<myArray.length; i++){
     document.write("<tr><td>" + myArray[i] + "</td>");
     document.write("<td>" + myArray2[i] + "</td>");
     document.write("<td>" + myArray3[i] + "</td>");
     document.write("<td>" + myArray4[i] + "</td></tr>");
} 

 </script>
 </table>
 </div>
 <html>
```

I have to place images into a table, only using java script.

I have this so far., and i am unsure of how to get the images to actually display as actual images for the javascript table.
My teacher told us to use document.write, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Why are you wrapping all of those file names into an _additional_ array?

Comment: _“how to get the images to actually display as actual images”_ - well what do you use to get an image displayed in HTML alone, if JavaScript wasn’t involved at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use something like below for image:

```
document.write("<tr><td><img src='" + myArray[i] + "'</td>");
```

Comment: Thanks jagrati Modi-AIS for your help in helping me in solving my dilemma, it has helped me greatly, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the question below, which did work how I needed it to.

How do I style the images when they are placed in the JavaScript table to not have any spaces between them.

document.write("<img src='" + myArray[i] + "'");